# Unable to create a PDA TokenAccount using anchor constraints

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, pda

I am trying to create a PDA `TokenAccount` and transfer an NFT from the users (signer) account to the created PDA. For some reason the PDA is not being created. After the transfer when i try to read the amount of token in users account, its still 1 and the PDA accounts balance is 0. Also i tried to load the PDA account from typescript but anchor is giving `TokenAccountNotFoundError` when tests run. Fairly new to solana so cant pinpoint the exact error. Any help will be appreciated.

Code:
Lp.rs

```
pub struct LPAcc<'info> {
    #[account(
      init,
      payer = user,
      space = Position::LEN,
      seeds = [b"pos".as_ref(), details.key().as_ref(), nft_mint.key().as_ref()],
      bump
    )]
    pub position: Account<'info, Position>,

   #[account(
     init,
     payer = user,
     associated_token::mint = nft_mint,
     associated_token::authority = position,
   )]
   pub nft_hldr: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
   ...
   ...
}
pub fn handler(ctx: Context<LPAcc>)-> Result(){

     //transfer nft
     let cpi_accounts = Transfer{
        from: ctx.accounts.nft_token_user_acc.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.nft_hldr.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
     };

     let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();

     transfer(CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts), 1)?;

     msg!("amount of tokens {0} {1} {2}", ctx.accounts.nft_hldr.key(), ctx.accounts.nft_hldr.key.amount, ctx.accounts.nft_token.amount );
}
```

Code test.ts:

```
  it("execute lp test", async () => {
      const [lpPos] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
         utils.bytes.utf8.encode("pos"),
         details.toBytes(),
         nft_mint.toBytes()
       ], programId);
      const nftHldr = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(position_mint, lpPos, true);

      const tx = await program.methods.handler()
     .accounts({
       details: details,
       position: lpPos,
       nftTokenUser: nftTokenUserAcc,
       nftMint: nftMint,
       nftHldr: nftHldr,
       user: wallet.publicKey,
       tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
       associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
       systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .signers([testWallet])
    .rpc()
    ownerTokenAccount  = await getAccount(connection, nftHldr) //Errors out here: TokenAccountNotFoundError
    console.log("ownerTokenAccount custody", ownerTokenAccount) 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1- The seeds of your position acc are wrong.

This is incorrect-   `b"pos".as_ref()`.

Use this instead:

```
 seeds = [b"pos", details.key().as_ref(), nft_mint.key().as_ref()],
```

Comment: how is this wrong?

Comment: seeds = [b"pos", details.key().as_ref(), nft_mint.key().as_ref()] 
instead

Comment: i have fixed it but still the same issue

Comment: can you share the LPAcc complete struct?